# how to search elements in mySQL table for comma separated elements from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables 'A' and 'B'. Table A has a field that is comma-separated values as follows :
Table A (fields : project_name, model_types)

```
  |project_name |    | model_types                                      |
  project_animals      detection,segmentation,detection,classification
```

I have table B with some information related to each model type listed above.

Table B (fields : model,labels,image_types)

```
| model       |   labels  | image_types |
detection     |   cat,dog | jpg,png
segmentation  |   rat,dog | jpg,tif
classification|   cow,cat | bmp,png
```

I need to read the labels and image_types for each model type listed in table A with a comma separate string. (no need to find unique)

Using the following SQL script, I could get the model_types string

```
select model_types from A where project_name = 'project_animals'
```

This will return model_types = 'detection,segmentation,detection,classification'.

So instead of reading table B with each item separately splited (model_types.split(',') outside mySQL and read again, how could I do it once in mySQL script.

So I need the results as follows from a single mySQL statement :

```
Model_types    |  labels  | image_types 
detection         cat,dog   jpg,png 
segmentation      rot,dog   jpg,tif 
detection         cat,dog   jpg,png 
classification    cow,cat   bmp,png
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you probably won't like the result. It's not possible to optimize searches on comma-separated strings (or any other substring matching, or regular expressions, etc.). So the query is bound to do a table-scan to find matches rows in table B.

```
SELECT tableB.*
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON FIND_IN_SET(tableB.model, tableA.model_types)
WHERE project_name = 'project_animals';
```

The FIND_IN_SET() expression can't use an index. Also it won't work if your comma-separated list contains spaces.

The proper way to store and query multi-valued attributes is to create another child table, and store multiple rows, with one model value per row.

For example, you could create a table `project_models`:

| project_name | model |
| --- | --- |
| project_animals | detection |
| project_animals | segmentation |
| project_animals | detection |
| project_animals | classification |

Then join this way:

```
SELECT tableB.*
FROM project_models
JOIN tableB ON tableB.model = project_models.model
WHERE project_models.project_name = 'project_animals';
```

This can use an index on `tableB.model` to optimize the join.

---

Besides this optimization problem, using a comma-separated list causes numerous other problems. See my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: This is great. I completely agree with you, but in this case, I have to use the already created tables. But this helps.